# Poor network throughput, but double under high cpu load

Tags: linux, networking, cpu-usage, gigabit-ethernet

I'm trying to understand a counter-intuitive phenomenon where I get only ~ 400 Mbit/s through a gigabit connection when the CPU is idle, but ~ 850 Mbit/s when the CPU is under full load (stress test utility). I suspect this is a symptom of some misconfiguration, in the end I would like to be able to saturate the link regardless of the CPU usage. The question is: what could cause the poor network performance, and why does it depend on the CPU usage in this strange way?

I'm glad for any hints, thanks for your time!

### Systems and hardware

- Lynx SENYO Mini PC ([GE5 PCF55](http://www.fic.com.tw/product/spec/ge5.pdf)) running up-to-date Arch Linux kernel version 5.0.8 (called the **client** for reference).
- NIC is a Realtek RTL8168:

  ```
  # lspci -nn | grep Ethernet
  08:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 03)
  ```
- Connection: CAT 6 patch cable <-> CAT 7 in-wall  cable <-> CAT 6 patch field <-> HPE OfficeConnect Switch <-> CAT 6 patch cable <-> supermicro home server (called the **server** for reference). Another PC gets ~ 950 Mbit/s on the exact same connection to the server with the exact same cables, so I guess this isolates the problem to the client.

### Test setup

- On the server:

  ```
  # iperf3 -D -s --bind 192.168.128.1
  ```
- On the client while CPUs are idle:

  ```
  # iperf3 -c 192.168.128.1
  Connecting to host 192.168.128.1, port 5201
  [  5] local 192.168.128.100 port 60738 connected to 192.168.128.1 port 5201
  [ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate         Retr  Cwnd
  [  5]   0.00-1.00   sec  39.8 MBytes   333 Mbits/sec    0    310 KBytes       
  [  5]   1.00-2.00   sec  40.5 MBytes   339 Mbits/sec    0    322 KBytes       
  [  5]   2.00-3.00   sec  40.3 MBytes   338 Mbits/sec    0    322 KBytes       
  [  5]   3.00-4.00   sec  41.0 MBytes   344 Mbits/sec    0    322 KBytes       
  [  5]   4.00-5.00   sec  36.9 MBytes   310 Mbits/sec    0    322 KBytes       
  [  5]   5.00-6.00   sec  53.1 MBytes   445 Mbits/sec    0    322 KBytes       
  [  5]   6.00-7.00   sec  53.7 MBytes   450 Mbits/sec    0    322 KBytes       
  [  5]   7.00-8.00   sec  54.7 MBytes   459 Mbits/sec    0    338 KBytes       
  [  5]   8.00-9.00   sec  54.0 MBytes   453 Mbits/sec    0    338 KBytes       
  [  5]   9.00-10.00  sec  54.0 MBytes   453 Mbits/sec    0    338 KBytes       
  - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
  [ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate         Retr
  [  5]   0.00-10.00  sec   468 MBytes   393 Mbits/sec    0             sender
  [  5]   0.00-10.04  sec   467 MBytes   390 Mbits/sec                  receiver
  ```
- On the client while running `stress -c 4` (all four CPUs busy on 100%)

  ```
  # iperf3 -c 192.168.128.1
  Connecting to host 192.168.128.1, port 5201
  [  5] local 192.168.128.100 port 60742 connected to 192.168.128.1 port 5201
  [ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate         Retr  Cwnd
  [  5]   0.00-1.00   sec   102 MBytes   854 Mbits/sec    0    356 KBytes       
  [  5]   1.00-2.00   sec   101 MBytes   845 Mbits/sec    0    375 KBytes       
  [  5]   2.00-3.00   sec   101 MBytes   846 Mbits/sec    0    392 KBytes       
  [  5]   3.00-4.00   sec   101 MBytes   844 Mbits/sec    0    409 KBytes       
  [  5]   4.00-5.00   sec   100 MBytes   843 Mbits/sec    0    409 KBytes       
  [  5]   5.00-6.00   sec   101 MBytes   843 Mbits/sec    0    409 KBytes       
  [  5]   6.00-7.00   sec   101 MBytes   845 Mbits/sec    0    409 KBytes       
  [  5]   7.00-8.00   sec   100 MBytes   841 Mbits/sec    0    451 KBytes       
  [  5]   8.00-9.00   sec   101 MBytes   843 Mbits/sec    0    451 KBytes       
  [  5]   9.00-10.00  sec   101 MBytes   851 Mbits/sec    0    510 KBytes       
  - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
  [ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate         Retr
  [  5]   0.00-10.00  sec  1008 MBytes   846 Mbits/sec    0             sender
  [  5]   0.00-10.04  sec  1005 MBytes   840 Mbits/sec                  receiver
  ```

### Unsuccessful attempts

- I thought maybe its a frequency scaling issue, but `cpupower frequency-set -g performance` makes no difference.
- Reading about issues with my specific NIC, I tried both drivers, the one present in the kernel (r8169) and the one from Realtek (r8168). The general picture is the same, the numbers are a bit different. With the Realtek driver I get 556 Mbits/s (idle CPU) vs 788 Mbits/s (busy CPU).
- Cross-checked a live Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (kernel 4.18.0) with the same results.
- Running `irqbalance` makes no difference.
- Disabling IPv6 makes no difference.

### Additional information (glad to add more on request)

Output from `ip`

```
# ip addr show dev enp8s0
2: enp8s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:14:0b:81:3f:8a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.128.100/24 brd 192.168.128.255 scope global noprefixroute enp8s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Output from `ethtool`:

```
# ethtool enp8s0
Settings for enp8s0:
        Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                                1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
        Supported pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Supported FEC modes: Not reported
        Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                                1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
        Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
        Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                             100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                                             1000baseT/Full 
        Link partner advertised pause frame use: No
        Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Link partner advertised FEC modes: Not reported
        Speed: 1000Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Port: MII
        PHYAD: 0
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: on
        Supports Wake-on: pumbg
        Wake-on: g
        Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
                               drv probe ifdown ifup
        Link detected: yes

# ethtool -i enp8s0
driver: r8169
version: 
firmware-version: rtl_nic/rtl8168d-1.fw
expansion-rom-version: 
bus-info: 0000:08:00.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: no
supports-eeprom-access: no
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: no
```

Interrupts:

```
# cat /proc/interrupts 
           CPU0       CPU1       CPU2       CPU3       
...
 26:     145689          0          0     394154   PCI-MSI 4194304-edge      enp8s0
...

# cat /proc/softirqs 
                    CPU0       CPU1       CPU2       CPU3       
          HI:          1         42         46          1
       TIMER:      11550      32469      10688      11494
      NET_TX:      85221          4          7     189091
      NET_RX:     145692          0         14     394372
       BLOCK:         21        450         39      22765
    IRQ_POLL:          0          0          0          0
     TASKLET:     136092         93         97     384278
       SCHED:      10554      29735       8720       9726
     HRTIMER:          0          0          0          0
         RCU:       6154       8303       5838       6506
```